# Can PostgreSQL recommend optimal field types?

Tags: postgresql, types

MySQL offers [`PROCEDURE ANALYSE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html). Given a query like

```
SELECT `field` FROM `table` PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

The result offers a suggested field type

```
Optimal_fieldtype: TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Does PostgreSQL offer a similar functionality? I've looked at **[pg_statistic](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-statistic.html)**/**[pg_stats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/view-pg-stats.html)**. Seems like I can use this information to infer what data type might be appropriate, but it would be handy if Postgres could recommend an actual data type itself.

Comment: It depends on the meaning of "optimal". For example, compare least-space-required to longest-time-til-wrap-around; these are likely to be opposites, yet both are "optimal".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Postgres for MySQL's `PROCEDURE ANALYSE` that I know of. (And I think I would know.)

For the given example, obviously about an integer-type column, I would:

```
SELECT min(field), max(field) FROM tbl;
```

And check against the range of possible [numeric data types in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html).

Or for the distribution of distinct values:

```
SELECT field, count(*) AS ct FROM tbl GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Actually, any DBA with a minimum of experience should know the essential characteristics of basic data types. The best type for each use case depends on a lot more than the current range and distribution of values. MySQL's `PROCEDURE ANALYSE()` would basically be assistance to newcomers - who would easily misinterpret results.

Comment: Determining the cardinality for a limited dataset is possible. Imposing it on the future is not. Data modelling can not be done without ... data modelling.

Comment: This may not be the usual use case, but for read-only databases (that is, @wildplasser 's "limited dataset") an automated optimization function would be quite useful. It's the difference between a table listing "Wars" and "Wars of the Roses"